# Alpinejs call method when variable changes

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Using `Alpine.js` for the first time.

I have a `video` tag to show the camera feed, in a modal, which is initialized when the `video` tag is initialized using

```html
<div x-data="initTestData()" @data-transfer.window="check=$event.detail.check; runningTest=true;" class="modal fade">

<video
    class="w-100 rounded"
    id="test-video"
    x-init="initTest(check)">
</video>

</div>
```

which is triggered by

```html
<i @click="$dispatch('data-transfer', {check: check})" data-bs-toggle="modal" role="button"></i>
```

and the js is defined as

```js
function initTestData() {
        console.log('init test data');
        return {
            check: null,
            resource: null,
            runningTest: false,
            initTest(check) {
                console.log('Check initialized: ', check);

                    const video = document.getElementById('test-video');
                    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                      video: {
                        facingMode: 'user'
                      }
                    }).then(stream => {
                      this.resource = stream;
                      // Older browsers may not have srcObject
                      if ("srcObject" in video) {
                        video.srcObject = stream;
                      } else {
                        // Avoid using this in new browsers, as it is going away.
                        // @ts-ignore
                        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                      }
                      video.onloadedmetadata = function () {
                        video.play();
                      };
                    });
                
            },
            closeTest(check) {
                this.runningTest = false;
                if (this.resource) {
                    let tracks = this.resource.getTracks(); // get all tracks from the media stream
                    tracks.forEach(track => track.stop()); // stop each track
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the `initTest()` method is called only once. After the modal is closed and opened again, the `initTest()` method is not called to reinitialise the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved by adding blank `x-data` on the `video` tag.

```html
<video
  x-data
  class="w-100 rounded"
  x-init="initTest(check);$watch('runningTest', (value) => value ? initTest(check) : '')"
  id="test-video">
</video>
```

It looks like `$watch` can only be used with `x-data` on the same element.

Answer (score 1):

*x-init* is called only once when the Alpine object is intialized.
When you close the modal the object is still there and *x-init* is no more invoked.

To resolve you can invoke *initTest()* in the event handler:

```
@data-transfer.window="check=$event.detail.check; runningTest=true; initTest(check)"
```

and remove `x-init="initTest(check)"`

---

Another option can be adding a *$watch* over a variable:

```js
function initTestData() {

    return {
     
       //.....

       init() {

           // this is a possible solution if 'check' is boolean, adapt it to your needings
    
           this.$watch('check', value => {
                value ? this.initTest() : this.closeTest();
       },
    
       //....
   }
}
```

And varying the value of the variable when dispatching the event.
For example:

```html
<i @click="$dispatch('data-transfer', {check: !check})">
```

But the event must be dispatched also in the modal *"dismiss"* to let closeTest() be called

Comment: I have put `x-init` on `video` tag because it should be called only after `video` tag is in dom. Otherwise it gives error as `video` tag is referred in the called method.